# PCF being too heavy

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-component-framework

I'm working with custom components from component framework and whenever I try to upload the file into CRM it says it's too heavy. I checked and it takes 7MB which is crazy since it shouldn't.
I'm using FluentUI and I checked my imports to see if there is anything importing something too big but it doesn't look like it.
Anyone could recommend me something that maybe I can found useful in order to check the file size?

I tried using source-map and source-map-explorer but I had an error everytime (the command during build wouldn't generate a json or similar errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take care of few things while you are importing FluentUI controls in your `index.ts` of PCF control.

You should be importing the controls in granular fashion - ie. import only needed controls. Otherwise `bundle.js` size will be huge like yours. Import the necessary controls using `@fluentui/react/lib/…` rather than the whole `@fluentui/react`.

And try building in **Release** mode instead of *Debug*. [Read more](https://dianabirkelbach.wordpress.com/2020/07/27/fluentui-granular-imports/)

You can check the `out` and `bin`folder contents.

[image]

[image]